# Import data from csv into a specific post

Tags: php, wordpress, import, advanced-custom-fields

I have multiple posts that has multiple custom fields on it. Now i need to add these fields from a excel/csv file. These files contain lots of info about this post. The problem i run into is that i don't see a way to import this content automatically. I don't seem to be able to use wp all import for this because it create a new item for each record and thats not what i want. All records need to be added as a custom field/repeater field.

If anyone has an idea on how to do this it would be much appreciated.

I tried to import this data using WP all import without succes.

Comment: Why doesn't WPAI work? As I understood it it you select a key to identify the posts to the CSV then it will update them rather than create new ones?

Answer (score 1):

```
function add_some_fields($file_url) {
    $data= array_map('str_getcsv', file($file_url));

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $post_id = $item[0]; // I hope you have post_id in that CSV file somewhere
        $field_name = $item[1] ; // ACF field name IF YOU HAVE IT IN CSV if not set manually, or make an array with names
        $col1 = $item[2]; //Value

        add_row( $field_name, $col1, $post_id ); //add row (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/add_row/)
    }
}
```

Call from where you want and how you want, usually I use condition in footer checking if custom GET parameter passed and if Yes then run function.